# Using the Twitter node in Node-RED

Tags: twitter, node-red

I have been using the "Twitter" node in Node-RED app and I have tried various alternatives.

If I use the node on the public stream for tweets containing the configured search term all I get is "rate limit hit" irrespective of the search term. I have tried #hybridcloud, #IoT and #cognitive

If I use the node to search all the tweets from accounts that I follow it works perfectly.

<del>If I use the node to search all tweets by specified users it does not appear to work at all. I can see no errors and even though I can tweets on Twitter itself nothing appears in app. I have used common twitter users like @IBMWatson, @NodeRED @the_jsf and @IBMBluemix</del>   **Now working**

I have used the same basic flow, see diagram, for each of the 3 variants.

[image]

Any assistance gratefully received.

Comment: Ignore the point about **"search all tweets by specified users"** it has started working with last @IBMBluemix id. I will try providing multiple users again separated by a comma to see if it works.

Comment: Are you running on Bluemix? If so then this issue may be the problem. https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/issues/253#issuecomment-268245862

Comment: Yes I am running in Bluemix **however,** I do not believe it is related to the Auth problem as it is working in the last 2 variants.

Comment: It's still likely to down to the rate limiting on an IP address/token basis